# Windows App Version : Possible to cancel after the certification done(Publish Manual)

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, uwpapps

I am planning to update my windows app with new version, So I have uploaded the build with highest version(Ex:new:1.1.1,storeversion:1.1.0) and completed the certification process. Now the app is in manual submitting option. It is waiting for the developer approval.

1) If I want to cancel this submission, Will it possible to do?  2) If yes, Will it window store allow to use the version again - 1.1.1? 3) Do I need to increase the version again?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*1) If I want to cancel this submission, Will it possible to do?*

No, it is impossible. Your app has been completed the certification process,and it is in the process of **Publishing**.Once **Publishing** phase has begun, you can no longer cancel your submission or change its release date.
You can get more details in document : [Publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/the-app-certification-process#publishing)

*2) If yes, Will it window store allow to use the version again - 1.1.1?*

You need to know three tips:

1. The version should have four section not three
2. For Windows 10 (UWP) packages, the last (fourth) section of the version number is reserved for Store use and must be left as 0 when you build your package (although the Store may change the value in this section).
3. You can submit packages in any order; you are not limited to providing higher-versioned packages with each subsequent submission

*3) Do I need to increase the version again?*

It depends on your needs.You can provide multiple UWP packages with the same version number. However, packages that share a version number cannot also have the same architecture, because the full identity that the Store uses for each of your packages must be unique. You could refer to 
[Version numbering for Windows 10 packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/package-version-numbering#version-numbering-for-windows10-packages) for more details.